# FileOutputStream creates file even if i check file existance

Tags: java, sockets

I'm making simple Client-Server application to make file copies on server.

There is clientside method for sending file to server:

```
private void makeCopy(Socket clientSock) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("D:\\client\\toCopy.bmp");
        File dest = new File("D:\\server\\copyFile.bmp");
        boolean ifExists = dest.exists();
        if(ifExists && !file.isDirectory()){
            System.out.println("Copy is already made on server.");
        }
        else{
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            while (fis.read(buffer) > 0) {
                oos.write(buffer);
            }
            //fis.close();
            oos.close();
        }

    }
```

Also there is serverside method for receiving file from client:

```
public void saveFile(Socket s) throws IOException{

        File copy = new File("D:\\server\\fileCopy.bmp");
        fos = new FileOutputStream(copy);
        File fromServer = new File("D:\\client\\toCopy.bmp");
        if(copy.exists() && !copy.isDirectory()){

        }
        else{
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

            int filesize = (int)fromServer.length();
            int read = 0;
            int totalRead = 0;
            int remaining = filesize;
            while((read = ois.read(buffer, 0, Math.min(buffer.length, remaining))) > 0) {
                totalRead += read;
                remaining -= read;
                System.out.println("read " + totalRead + " bytes.");
                fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is, even if i check file existance it still makes file which I can't open (it has 0 bytes written). Any ideas ?

Comment: This code does not produce zero length files unless you send zero length files. How can a client possibly check what is on a server with the `File` class? Your question doesn't make sense. NB Your client copy loop is incorrect. Plenty of correct examples here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

FileOutputStream creates a file output stream and a file in a file system.
First you should check existence and then create FileOutputStream.

```
File copy = new File("D:\\server\\fileCopy.bmp");
if(copy.exists() && !copy.isDirectory()){ }
fos = new FileOutputStream(copy);
File fromServer = new File("D:\\client\\toCopy.bmp");
```

Comment: Why? Your second line of code accomplishes exactly nothing. It can be simplly removed.